# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: 10.04, mysql

My mysql installation was screwed up. I uninstalled and installed it multiple times. But I kept getting a hang or a error "cant connect". I now finally have it running with `sudo -u mysql mysqld`. How do I get mysqld to run at startup, and why do I need to run it as user `mysql`. Can I change it to run as root ?

Edit

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             230G  5.5G  213G   3% /
none                  2.0G  268K  2.0G   1% /dev
none                  2.0G  3.2M  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
none                  2.0G   92K  2.0G   1% /var/run
none                  2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /var/lock
none                  2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda5             230G   20G  199G   9% /home
```

Comment: How about starting mysql as a service? Like `sudo service mysql start`
What is the output from the above command?

Comment: I get this error `start: Job failed to start`

Comment: Where do you store your mysql data? Is the partition which stores those data full? By the way, check mysql log files at `/var/log/mysql.log` and `/var/log/mysql.err`

Comment: Both the files are empty. Worse case scenario.

Comment: How about `df -h`? What is the output of the command?

Comment: edited on question

Comment: Try uninstalling it and also remove all the files present in `/var/lib/mysql` and `/etc/mysql`. Then reinstall. Worked for me.

Comment: That is what I did, I uninstalled and after a lot of pain, got it to be installed and working. I think its a permission chown issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add mysql as a service with `sudo service mysql start` as Minh Danh said in the comment.

Daemons are given their own users to allow for better permissions control.